# What is causing 'compileSdkVersion is not specified' error in React Native app build.gradle file?

Tags: java, android, react-native, build.gradle

```
$ npx react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
                                                                                                                                  
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.                                                                                         

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\prami\OneDrive\Desktop\Gps_Tracker\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\android\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-safe-area-context'.
> Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-safe-area-context'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I am facing the issue from last three days still not able to resolve can any one help me in resolving the issue?

I checked the compileSdkVersion in build.gradle file, everything is fine, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: This is where the scanned details is present = https://scans.gradle.com/s/nvmfcc45awwje/failure#1